# recognize the face & distort it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opencv, image-recognition, face-recognition

We have to create an application which can take a photograph and can recognize the face and can distort it in a certain way. Below is an example:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fatbooth/id372268904?mt=8

Any ideas? Is it possible using OpenCV library only?

Comment: Second that. 11 questions, not one answer accepted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can ado that using OpenCV. First you need to detect the face. There is Haar cascade based face detector in OpencCV. After that you can detect the facial landmark points using the same interface. But you need to train the landmark detectors like eye corners, eye center, mouth, chin etc. Once you get those points you can do different kind of warps by displacing the points.

Answer (score 0):

**Updating for iOS5:** If you are targeting iOS5+, you don't need openCV - in iOS5 you can do simple face detection using the Apple provided methods.